# Find and select a row in QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview, qtgui

I have a QWidget which contains a QTableView..A find dialog is poped up after pressing Ctrl+F.
I want to select the row (rows) which contain the text entered in find dialog in their first column.

I have this code but the problem is that it does not do the row selecting, please guide me whether i have a good approach for finding matches and selecting the corresponding row in the table. Problem is that the following code can not find matches and select them.

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,md,parent=None):
      QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
      layout=QVBoxLayout(self)

      # initially construct the visible table
      self.table = QTableView()
      self.table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)  # uncomment this if the last column shall cover the rest
      self.table.show()

      # set black grid lines
      self.setStyleSheet("gridline-color: rgb(39, 42, 49)")

      # construct the Qt model belonging to the visible table
      model = NvmQtModel(md)
      self.table.setModel(model)
      self.table.resizeRowsToContents()
      self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()

      # set the shortcut ctrl+F for find in menu
      shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence('Ctrl+f'), self)
      shortcut.activated.connect(self.handleFind)

    # shows and handles the find dialog
    def handleFind(self):
        findDialog = QDialog()
        findDialog.setWindowTitle("Find")
        grid = QGridLayout()
        findDialog.setLayout(grid)

        findLabel = QLabel("Find what", findDialog)
        grid.addWidget(findLabel,1,0)
        findField = QLineEdit(findDialog)
        grid.addWidget(findField,1,1)
        findButton = QPushButton("Find", findDialog)
        grid.addWidget(findButton,2,1)
        findButton.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.find(findField.text()))
        print("Hereee1")
        findDialog.exec_()

    # find function: search in the first column of the table   
    def find(self, text, column=0):
        print("Hereee2")
        model = self.table.model()
        start = model.index(0, column)
        matches = model.match(
        start, Qt.DisplayRole,
        text, 1, Qt.MatchContains)
        print(text)
        if matches:
            index = matches[0]
            # index.row(), index.column()
            self.table.selectionModel().select(
                index, QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Select)
            print("Hereee3")
```

Comment: Please show the output of the print statements, and also show some sample text from the first column of the table. Are you sure the text being searched for is in that column? Please also say whether you are using python2 or python3.

Comment: Console Output: Hereee1
Hereee2
NVM_XTURN

Comment: As u see Heree3 is not printed! but i have NVM... in the first column. I am using python 2.7

Comment: What is `NvmQtModel`? I tested with a standard item model, and it works fine for me.

Comment: NNvmQtModel is a QAbstractTableModel..

Comment: Is it a custom model you wrote yourself? Does it re-implement lots of methods (such as `match()`)?

Comment: I don't have method "match" in tableModel...!!

Comment: Yes, it's another class : class NvmQtModel(QAbstractTableModel)

Comment: I just modified your example code to use a simple standard item model, and it works as expected. There's obviously a problem with the `NvmQtModel`, but it's impossible to say what it is without seeing the code. Am I to assume this is not code you wrote yourself?